# Passing a url to a dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I created an image gallery with dynamic div's and want to add an onclick event to the div but I get an error "ReferenceError: pag1 is not defined" What am I doing wrong.  Below is my code.

```
var btnInfo=[
    {
        img: 'images/thumbs/img1.jpg',
        id: 'btn1',
        title: 'Kingsman',
        projectUrl: 'pag1.html'
    },
    {
        img: 'images/thumbs/img2.jpg',
        id: 'btn2',
        title: 'Title Two',
        projectUrl: 'page2.html'
    }
]

for(var i=0; i<btnInfo.length; i++){
  $('.thumbWrapper .container ul' ).append('<li id="'+btnInfo[i].id+' "    onclick="getProject('+btnInfo[i].projectUrl+' )"><div class="view view-tenth"><img src="'+btnInfo[i].img+'"><div class="mask"><h2>'+btnInfo[i].title+'</h2></div></div></li>');
}

function getProject(url){
        var w = url;
        console.log("url " + url);
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `page1.html`

Comment: that is, in your first object, in your "projectUrl" property

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting the argument in the `onclick` handler without quotes, should be

```
... onclick="getProject(\''+btnInfo[i].projectUrl+'\' )"><div class="view view-tenth">
//                       ^^                        ^^ needs escaped quotes
```

But why not just use jQuery

```
$('.thumbWrapper .container ul' ).append(
    btnInfo.map(function(item) {
        return $('<li />', {
            id : item.id,
            on : {
                click : function() {
                    getProject(item.projectUrl)
                }
            }
        }).append(
            $('<div />', {'class' : 'view view-tenth'}),
            $('<img />', {src : item.img}),
            $('<div />', {'class' : 'mask'}).append(
                 $('<h2 />', {text : item.title})
            )
        )
    })
)
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/80cshbg8/1/)

Comment: On the contrary, shouldn't it rather have double quotes? like this:
`onclick="getProject('"+btnInfo[i].projectUrl+"' )"><div...`

Comment: @EisaAdil - that would produce `onclick="getProject("pag1.html")"` which seems rather invalid

Comment: I don't think so
`onclick="getProject('pag1.html')"` is what it should produce

Comment: As a whole it should be this:
`onclick="getProject('"+btnInfo[i].projectUrl+"')><div class=\"view view-tenth\"><img src="`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100271/discussion-between-eisa-adil-and-adeneo).